# electron nested msi installer

Tags: windows-installer, electron, installation

I'm trying to make one big `msi` installer with multiple `msi` installers in it.

So, let's say I have `main-msi`, `a-msi`, `b-msi`.

```
main-msi(starts installing)
main-msi(pause installing)
    a-msi(starts installing & finish installing)
    b-msi(starts installing & finish installing)
main-msi(finish installing)
```

Is it possible to make nested `msi` installer using electron?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this for at least two reasons:

1. How do you propose pausing an MSI-based install? They just run, showing (usually) some UI choices and then just go. At the progress stage there isn't a way to say "wait for a while". It's a Windows process, msiexec.exe.
2. MSI-based installs are transactional system-wide. Once the main part of the install has started no others can start. They'd see error 1618 "Another install is in progress".